# E/wifidirectdemo(20281): bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: android, wifi, share, bind, wifi-direct

I am using a wifidirect sample to send a file to client many times .Each time i close the serverSocket and clientShocket but on the second time i am getting the following error

06-07 12:01:22.477: E/wifidirectdemo(20281): bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

And again i am able to send the file once kill the app .

https://github.com/anuj7sharma/WiFiDIrectDemo

Thank you ..

Comment: Following are my code :

Comment: i m getting the error on                                                                                 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); this line when try to connect the device second times ..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?